# Mark a selected image as "checked" when click with jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to do this for a long time but no success...
See

CSS

```
    .images_list li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.border {
    border: 6px solid #D8D8D8;
    background: url(upload/check.jpg);
}
.selected {
    border: 6px solid green;
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:119px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    width:31px;
    height:150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="images_list">
  <li class="border" title="content_1">
      <img src="http://imagensface.com.br/imagens/imagens-lindas-imagens-ace558.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
      <span>
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blue-bits/24/symbol-check-icon.png" />
      </span>
    </li>
  <li class="border" title="content_2">
      <img src="http://www.p69.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/imagens-lindas-6.jpg?0bce15" width="150" height="150" />
      <span>
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blue-bits/24/symbol-check-icon.png" />
      </span>
    </li>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="img_info">
  <div id="content_1" class="content hidden">content1</div>
        <div id="content_2" class="content hidden">content2</div>
      </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.images_list li').click(function() {
            $('.images_list .selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
            $("#"+clicked).removeClass("hidden").siblings().addClass("hidden");
        });
```

I manage to change the border color but i want to put that check image on the top of the image selected. When nothing is selected, that check will be hidden.
Anny suggestions?

the "working" example http://jsfiddle.net/6kSsd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is your span style, you are targeting all spans here, you should target only those spans in the image list

change

```
span {
```

to

```
.images_list li span {
```

And to position the span to the top corner use `top:0px` `left:0px`, and get rid of the margin and padding styles as they are not needed, also add display:none so they are not initially shown.

```
.images_list li span {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
}
```

Then to show the checkmark when its parent is selected

```
.images_list li.selected span {
    display:block;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6kSsd/4/)

Comment: Can you help me with another problem?My span when hovered, change the image to a minus icon, to remove the selection. How can i make this work?

Answer (score 0):

> I manage to change the border color but i want to put that check image on the top of the image selected. When nothing is selected, that check will be hidden. Anny suggestions?

Have you tried hiding the "check image" and showing it only when the parent element has the class selected? The following CSS will do the trick:

```
.images_list li > span {
    display: none;
}
.images_list li.selected > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

Please note that `<li>` is only allowed in `<ul>` and `<ol>` *not* within `<div>`. `<br>` is for a forced break in text - if you need to make space between elements, the CSS property `margin` is your friend.

Comment: actually, this is only for demo purposes, my code is more clean than this! thanks!